# What is causing this "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'provides')" while upgrading project from Vuetify 2.x to 3.x?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, webpack, vuetify.js, vuetifyjs3

I'm in the process of upgrading a project that is Vue 2.6.x using Vuetify 2.x for it's UI. I've worked my way through a number of difficulties but haven't been able to figure this one out.

I am using `@vue/compat` to use Vue 3 in 2.x compatibility mode.

I run `npm run serve` and it doesn't throw any errors but when I load the app in the browser nothing is displayed. Looking at the browser console I can see that it is throwing this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'provides') 
    at Object.install (theme.mjs:189:1) 
    at Object.install (framework.mjs:43:1) 
    at Vue.use (vue.runtime.esm-bundler.js:7224:1)
    at eval (main.ts:28:1)
    at ./src/main.ts (app.js:349:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:2942:33)
    at app.js:4083:96
    at __webpack_require__.O (app.js:3001:23)
    at app.js:4084:53
    at app.js:4086:12
 install    @   theme.mjs:189
 install    @   framework.mjs:43
 Vue.use    @   vue.runtime.esm-bundler.js:7224
 eval   @   main.ts:28
 ./src/main.ts  @   app.js:349
 __webpack_require__    @   app.js:2942
 (anonymous)    @   app.js:4083
 __webpack_require__.O  @   app.js:3001
 (anonymous)    @   app.js:4084
 (anonymous)    @   app.js:4086
```

One can see that it is having issues in `main.ts` at line 28:

```
Vue.use(vuetify);
```

Here is some surrounding context to help (or if you are really adventurous you can get the latest from the branch available here: https://github.com/davidshq/miqa/tree/support-multiple-proxy-managers-3-3):

```js
// main.ts
import Vue from 'vue';
import { createVuetify } from 'vuetify';
import * as components from 'vuetify/components';
import * as directives from 'vuetify/directives';

import App from '/App.vue';
import router from './router';
import { store } from './store';

const vuetify = createVuetify( {
  components,
  directives,
});

Vue.use(vuetify);
Vue.use(store);
Vue.use(snackbarService(vuetify));
Vue.use(promptService(vuetify));

Vue.config.productionTip = true;

(async () => {
 // Do some API calls
 // ...

 new Vue({
  vuetify,
  router,
  store,
  render: (h) => h(App),
})
 .$mount('#app')
 .$snackbarAttach();
 .$promptAttach();
})();
```

I've tried to leave as much as possible in 2.x form so I can focus on getting Vuetify working and then finish the migration to 3.x.

Vuetify related plugins in `package.json` include the following:

```json
"dependencies": {
 "@vue/compat": "^3.2.47",
 "vuetify": "^3.1.4",
 "vue": "^3.2.47",
 "vue-router": "^3.4.3",
 "vuex": "^4.1.0"
},
"devDependencies": {
 "eslint-plugin-vuetify": "^2.0.0-beta.2",
 "webpack": "^5.75.0",
 "webpack-plugin-vuetify": "^2.0.1"
}
```

Any suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: The first natural question is, what is the minimum that you can reproduce this with? Does it work or fail on an empty 2.6/3.x repo? When you start adding your own components, at which step does it fail?